# "Wir Deutsche" oder "wir Deutschen"?

Tags: grammaticality

> "Heißt es: Wir Deutsche fürchten Gott, sonst niemand in der Welt, oder wir Deutschen -?" gebe ich zu bedenken. (*E.M.Remarque. Im Westen nichts Neues.*)

Nach hundert Jahren stelle ich mir auch diese Frage - mit oder ohne "n"?

Und eine Nebenfrage - wie hat Bismarck diesen Satz in seiner Rede tatsächlich gesagt? Im Internet gibt es beide Varianten.

Comment: Ähnlich, auf Englisch: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/52004/35111

Comment: Ok, habe wohl die Gesamtkomplexität des Themenkreises unterschätzt und meine Antwort zurückgezogen :-) Mir war gar nicht bewußt das es zwar 'wir Deutsche' aber 'die Deutschen' sind, während 'wir Engländer' und 'die Engländer' gleich dekliniert wird. Könnte mit der Endung zusammenhängen. Ein schlauer Kollege wird's sicher aufklären.

Comment: Die Nebenfrage ist hier off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dies ist ein bekannter Zweifelsfall. Beides ist möglich. Heutzutage tritt jedoch die Form «wir Deutschen» häufiger auf.

### Wie kommt es zu der Schwankung?

Das Wort «Deutsche» ist, grammatisch gesehen, ein Adjektiv (denn Adjektive sind diejenigen Wörter, die nach [Definitheit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definitheit_(Linguistik)), [Numerus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerus), [Genus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus) und [Komparation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komparation) deklinieren). In der grammatischen Kategorie der Definitheit haben Adjektive starke oder schwache Endungen:

1. Starke Endung: *Deutsch**e** fürchten Gott.*
2. Schwache Endung: *Die Deutsch**en** fürchten Gott.*

Nota bene: Beide Fälle sind bzgl. der übrigen grammatischen Kategorien völlig gleich: Kasus ist Nominativ, Numerus Plural (daher Genus unbestimmt), Komparation Positiv. Ausserdem spielt es keine Rolle, ob auf das Adjektiv ein Substantiv folgt oder nicht (ausser für die Rechtschreibung):

3. Starke Endung: *Deutsch**e** Menschen fürchten Gott.*
4. Schwache Endung: *Die deutsch**en** Menschen fürchten Gott.*

Nach verschiedenen Wörtern, insbesondere nach unbestimmten Zahladjektiven ist der Gebrauch schwankend und es kommen sowohl starke als auch schwache Endungen vor, z.B. nach Wörtern wie *alle, andere, beide, einige, etliche, folgende, manche, mehrere, sämtliche, solche, viele, welche, wenige* (Liste aus meiner alten Duden-Grammatik):

5. Starke Endung: *Manche Deutsch**e** fürchten Gott.*
6. Schwache Endung: *Manche Deutsch**en** fürchten Gott.*

Ebenso ist dies der Fall nach Personalpronomen:

7. Starke Endung: *Wir Deutsch**e** fürchten Gott.*
8. Schwache Endung: *Wir Deutsch**en** fürchten Gott.*

Beides ist richtig.

### Welche Form ist häufiger?

Die Dudengrammatik *(Duden, Grammatik der deutschen Gegenwartssprache,* 6., neu bearbeitete Auflage, Mannheim, Leipzig Wien Zürich, 1998, §481: «Das Adjektiv nach Personalpronomen») beschreibt, dass die Schwankung zwischen starker und schwacher Endung im Dativ singular aller drei Genera und im Nominativ plural auftritt. Zum Nominativ plural – wie er in «wir Deutsche(n)» vorliegt – heisst es Folgendes (wobei mit «Typ II» die schwache Endung gemeint ist):

> Im Nom. Plur. wird heute das Adjektiv im Allgemeinen nach Typ II, also wie nach *diese,* gebeugt, bei *ihr* noch häufiger als bei *wir:*
>
> wir *erbärmlichen* Wichte, wir *älteren* Leute (Carossa), ihr *motorisierten* Narren (Kästner).

Der von tofro angeführte Artikel [*Wir Deutschen lieben Fussball* oder *Wir Deutsche lieben Fussball?* — Flexion von adjektivischen Bezeichnungen nach einem Personalpronomen](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/fragen/3167) des [IDS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz-Institut_f%C3%BCr_Deutsche_Sprache) weist darauf hin, dass bei einer Suche mit Google oder im IDS-Korpus die schwache Form «wir Deutschen» etwa doppelt so viele Treffer erzielt wie die starke Form «wir Deutsche». Dies deckt sich mit der zitierten Aussage aus der Dudengrammatik.

Nach Dudengrammatik und IDS ist also heutzutage nach «wir» die schwache Form «wir Deutschen» häufiger.

### Was hat Bismarck wirklich gesagt?

Laut dem zitierten Artikel des IDS ist Bismarcks Zitat häufiger mit starker Adjektiv-Endung in der Form «Wir Deutsche fürchten Gott» anzutreffen. Allerdings erscheine das Zitat schon im 19. Jahrhundert mit beiden Formen. Der Artikel meint lapidar:

> Übrigens spricht diese «Variatio» nicht unbedingt für die Genauigkeit der Zitierenden.

Laut dem Artikel des IDS habe Bismarck also eher «wir Deutsche» gesagt, doch sei es nicht sicher.

Comment: Sicher daß das stimmt ? "Wir Deutsche" mag ein substantiviertes Adjektiv sein, aber dann folgt es den Regeln eines Substantivs (wird beispielsweise groß geschrieben, und dekliniert wie ein Substantiv). "Wir Deutschen" aus der Frage hört sich nicht richtig an. "Die Deutschen" schon. Das 'n' im Nominativ scheint mit manchen Substantiven zu funktionieren, mit anderen nicht. Warum ?  Wäre zufrieden wenn die Antwort "weil es halt so ist" lautet.

Comment: @a_donda: Die sog. «Substantivierung» von Adjektiven ist eine rein orthografische Unsitte. Die Grammatik, sprich: die Deklination, bleibt davon völlig unberührt. Es heisst «ich Deutsche» genau so wie «ich deutsche Frau», «ich Deutscher» genau so wie «ich deutscher Mann». Kein Substantiv dekliniert so, völlig ausgeschlossen. Und wohl ist es so, dass wir Deutschsprachigen bzw. wir Deutschsprachige meistens eine der beiden Optionen vorziehen (für mich tönt «wir Deutschsprachigen» richtiger), aber trotzdem wird auch die andere verwendet. Beide sind richtig – so ist es halt.

Comment: Interessant. Ich bin Deutscher. "wir Deutsche" *ist* ein substantiviertes Adjektiv, ganz natürlich ohne Unsitte und 'n' (was der Duden ja auch so führt https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Deutsch). "wir Deutschen" gibt es wohl nicht (6. und 8.), es müßte "wir deutschen Leute/Bürger/.." heißen, dann ist es ein Adjektiv und wird entsprechend behandelt. Es gibt allerdings "die Deutschen" (Substantiv !). Ich denke die Antwort ist so nicht richtig, mache aber keinen Aufstand.

Comment: @a_donda: Du irrst dich. «Wir Deutschen» gibt es ganz gewiss, vgl. die Belege in dem von tofro angeführten Artikel [_Wir Deutschen lieben Fussball_ oder _Wir Deutsche lieben Fussball?_ — Flexion von adjektivischen Bezeichnungen nach einem Personalpronomen](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/fragen/3167). Und substantivierte Adjektive gefallen mir zwar nicht, aber ich bestreite nicht ihre Existenz, sondern weise lediglich darauf hin, dass es sich um ein rein orthografisches Phänomen handelt ohne grammatische Grundlage, denn grammatisch gesehen verhalten sich die Wörter weiterhin wie Adjektive.

Comment: Na da sind wohl wie du schreibst persönliche Ansichten. Ich halte mich eher an den Duden als an Internetblogs. Substantivierte Adjektive sind alltäglich.

Comment: @a_donda: Bliebe die Frage, warum du auf deiner persönlichen Ansicht beharrst, nur «wir Deutsche» wäre richtig, obwohl im Duden etwas anderes steht. Es ist ja eben gerade nicht meine persönliche Ansicht, dass sowohl «wir Deutschen» als auch «wir Deutsche» korrekt sind, sondern belegter Befund zweier hervorragenden Quellen zur deutschen Grammatik, nämlich des Dudens und des IDS.

Comment: @a_donda Die Substantivierung ändert nichts an der Flexion. Es heißt *Deutsch**e*** wie *Beamt**e*** mit starker Adjektivendung, aber *die Deutsch**en*** wie *die Beamt**en*** mit schwacher Adjektivendung. Die Form *wir Deutsch**en*** mit einer schwachen Endung wird vom [Wörterbuch](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Deutsche_Angehoerige_des_deutschen_Volkes), von der Duden-Grammatik und von dem verlinkten Artikel des Instituts für Deutsche Sprache als die verbreitetere anerkannt, daher ist die Aussage *"wir Deutschen" gibt es wohl nicht* falsch.

Comment: @DavidVogt Schon klar das mit der Substantivierung, (die natürlich ihre grammatische Grundlage hat). Ok, ich muß es wohl einsehen mit dem 'n' bei "wir Deutsche" (im Unterschied zu "die Deutschen"), auch wenn ich finde daß es sich falsch anhört, wie ein Akkusativ anstatt eines Nominativs. Na, wie dem auch sei ...

Comment: @a_donda: Soso, eine grammatische Grundlage der Substantivierung? Was wäre die denn bitteschön? Der Unterschied zwischen nicht substantivierten und substantivierten Adjektiven ist rein orthografisch. Einen grammatischen Unterschied kenne ich nicht. Auch die substantivierten Adjektive weisen alle grammatischen Merkmale der Adjektive auf, die bei Substantiven nicht existieren, nämlich Deklination nach Genus, Definitheit und Komparation. Das sind die grammatischen Merkmale der deutschen Adjektive.

Answer (score 3):

Substantive, die von Adjektiven abgeleitet werden (und das ist hier wohl der Fall), werden mit *adjektivischer Flektion* dekliniert. Das bedeutet:

- **Ohne Artikel**: Starke Flektion, *Deutsche*
- **mit bestimmtem Artikel**: Schwache Flektion, *die Deutschen*
- **mit unbestimmtem Artikel, Pronomen o.Ä**: Gemischte Flektion, *wir Deutschen*

Man vergleiche z.B. mit "alt":

- *Alte*
- *die Alten*
- *wir Alten*

Einen langen und durchaus interessanten Artikel dazu gibt es [hier](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/fragen/3167) . Der Artikel kommt zu dem Schluss, dass "wir Deutsche" so verbreitet sei, dass man es schon fast als "richtig" ansehen kann.

Comment: Sie werden so lange adjektivisch gebeugt, bis sie es nicht mehr werden, oder? Die Gerade erlaubt ja auch beides.

Comment: @CarstenS Den Satz verstehe ich nicht.

Comment: Was ich meinte, ist, dass ich denke, dass Worte, die ursprünglich substantivierte Adjektive sind, wenn sie nicht mehr als solche empfunden werden, die Deklination wechseln können. Wenn das so ist, wäre „die Gerade“ ein Beispiel. Da dachte ich, dass beide Deklinationen geläufig wären, aber nachdem ich in ein Wörterbuch geschaut habe, scheint „an einer Gerade“ auch noch als falsch zu gelten.

Comment: @CarstenS Ahjetztja. Ich kenne, ehrlich gesagt, kein Adjektiv, Partizip, o.Ä., das in jüngerer Zeit (also in der **deutschen** Sprachgeschichte) seine Deklination von der adjektivischen weg geändert hätte. Will aber nicht ausschließen, dass es das gibt.

Comment: Ich hatte das nur als Laie angenommen, aber da mein Beispiel keines war... (Es sei denn, es ist eines, genau wie "Deutsche", und ist nur nicht in den Wörterbüchern angekommen, aber das ist keine Diskussion, zu der ich sinnvoll etwas beitragen könnte.)

Comment: Ein Fall wie «wir Deutschen» ist nicht gemischte Flexion. Die gemischte Flexion tritt nur nach einigen Determinierern wie «kein» oder «ein» auf, die im Nominativ singular maskulin und neutrum endungslos sind (sowie im Akkusativ singular neutrum, der sich in indogermanischen Sprachen in aller Regel nicht vom Nominativ unterscheidet), so dass das Adjektiv die starke Endung übernimmt. Der Fall «wir Deutschen» ist hingegen einfach ein Zweifelsfall, wo entweder die starke oder die schwache Endung verwendet werden kann.

Comment: @mach die Literatur (Siehe Link) ist nicht deiner Meinung.

Comment: @tofro: Welche Literatur? Auf der verlinkten Seite finde ich die gemischte Flexion nirgendwo erwähnt (und es würde mich auch sehr überraschen, wenn das IDS bei Fällen wie «wir Deutschen» plötzlich von gemischter Deklination spräche). In der Dudengrammatik ist die gemischte Flexion so definiert, wie ich es beschrieben habe.

Comment: *Der Artikel kommt zu dem Schluss, dass "wir Deutsche" so verbreitet sei, dass man es schon fast als "richtig" ansehen kann.* Nein! Der Artikel weist darauf hin, daß nach dem Pronomen **starke** Flexion (*du Arm**er**, wir Deutsch**e***, *für uns Deutsch**e***) erwartet wird. Nur in der 1. und 2. Person Plural, und dort auch nur im Nominativ, gibt es eine Ausnahme und die **schwache** Flexion ist nicht nur möglich, sondern sogar verbreiteter als die starke: *wir Deutsch**en*** > *wir Deutsch**e***.